# Downloading all the current smart contract

Tags: solidity

I want to make a "big-data" analysis of smart contracts,

Is there a "crawler" out there, to retrieve all the smart-contract that are "active"?

(Another question is how can I verify whether the contract is still active)

Thank.

Comment: that is exactly what I am doing right now, writing my own crawler for the entire blockchain, just like etherscan.io. Maybe you don't need a crawler, because maybe you can use etherscan API and scan everything you need. All crawlers available out there that process internal transactions between contracts are outdated, and wont work. But if by some miracle you find some working code (that processes internal transactions) please let me know.

Comment: https://github.com/modernblockchains/newkidsontheblock/tree/master/ethereum-crawler

Comment: https://github.com/Arachnid/etherquery

Answer (score 2):

Use [QuickBlocks](https://quickblocks.io/). It allows you to scan every block looking for any data you're interested in. 
And it's up to date as per the Byzantium fork. Totally handles internal transactions. Better yet it does so in a fully decentralized way (i.e. it runs on your laptop).

(Full disclosure: I wrote [QuickBlocks](https://quickblocks.io/)).